# Modifying text and adding suffix to legend items in ArcGIS JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have put together a simple ArcGIS JS webapp that draws data from a webmap, which you can see [here](https://masteosdemo.surge.sh/).

I'm currently stuck at modifying the legend itens to include a percentage sign (%) after each class. So ideally the legend below would read 12%, 9%, 6%, etc. Haven't been able to do so with the ArcGIS JS API 4.24, and now am looking into ways of doing this by just selecting the classes and modifying the textelement with js an css, but still no success.

```
        let legend = new Legend({
          view: view
        });

        const legendExpand = new Expand({
            view:view,
            content:legend,
            expanded:true
        })

        view.ui.add(legendExpand, "bottom-right");
```

[image]

Comment: Is this based on an arcgis online webmap? Can you edit the legend there?

Comment: Yes, it's coming from a webmap, and no, there's no option to add suffix to the legend in ArcGIS Online without changing the data type to string.

Comment: Ok. That sounds familiar. I have one much more intensive way. Will post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the JSAPI to query the endpoint and get the legend data for the layer, then you could construct your own legend in html and the format it how you want.

Here is the start of querying a MapServer endpoint and sifting through to get your desired layer, then pulling the existing label and the swatch/color of the item. After that just make your html legend.

Probably a lot more work than you want, but possible. Your way of altering the text after the fact is probably a good bet. I haven't looked at that.

```
 function updateLegend(mapCategories, mapType, mapLegend, mapPermitComments, mapNotes, mapDescription) {
     //get generic Hayward MuniCodeURL. Will add each section as we go
     $.getJSON("https://maps.hayward-ca.gov/arcgis/rest/services/External/Hayward_WebApp/MapServer/legend?f=pjson", function (data) {
    //grab the legend data for the Zoning layer
    //break down the data object into array of web map services
    var webmapServices = Object.values(data)[0];
    //var to capture the index position of zoning layer
    var zoningIndex;

    //map over array of all service layers to find what index zoning is
   //zoning used to be hard coded but as the overall webmap service changes, the 
   //position of the zoning layer changes and breaks the app
        webmapServices.map(function(obj, index) {
            console.log(obj.layerName);
            if (obj.layerName === "Zoning") {
                zoningIndex = index;
            };
        });

    //get legend data from zoning layer
    allZoningData = data.layers[zoningIndex].legend;
    allZoningData.forEach(function (zone) {
        var thisArray = [];
            thisArray.push(zone.label);
            thisArray.push(zone.imageData);
```